# A opção do ESLint de "enforce code style" adiciona algum comportamento quando já estamos utilizando o Prettier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

Quando executamos `eslint --init`, nos deparamos primeiramente com a seguinte questão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Realizei dois testes, um selecionando "*To check syntax and find problems*" e outra utilizando "*To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style*", para essa ultima opção ainda escolhi a *Style Guide Standard*. Nos testes finais obtive o mesmo comportamento para estilização e linting.

**Minha dúvida é**: pelo fato de estar utilizando `prettier` com `eslint-config-prettier` e `eslint-plugin-prettier`, ainda assim é recomendado selecionar "*To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style*"? Pelo que pude entender analisando o projeto, ao utilizar Prettier isso seria desnecessário uma vez que o Prettier por padrão já é aderente a Style Guide Standard, porém ainda não tenho certeza se este raciocínio está correto.

Meu arquivo `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "standard",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente, não é algo necessário, visto que o Prettier já se responsabiliza pela formatação do código, isto é, realizar mudanças no "estilo" do código. Como, por exemplo:

- Ponto-e-vírgula (opcionais na maioria dos casos);
- Indentação;
- Tipo de aspas a ser usada (simples, duplas...);
- E mais opções.

Desse modo, não há a necessidade de fazer com que o ESLint iria acabar formatando o código, fazendo o papel do Prettier. Existe, inclusive, o [`eslint-config-prettier`](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier), que desativa todas as regras do ESLint que entrem em conflito com o Prettier:

> Turns off all rules that are unnecessary or might conflict with Prettier.

E, em relação ao título da pergunta, "*A opção do ESLint de “enforce code style” adiciona algum comportamento quando já estamos utilizado o Prettier?*", sim, ao fazer com que o ESLint também se responsabilize com o estilo do código, algumas regras serão adicionadas que podem, inclusive, entrar em conflito com o Prettier. É para isso, aliás, que foi criado o supracitado `eslint-config-prettier`.